# invalid char '&' manipulating variables in memory

Tags: assembly, x86, gnu-assembler, att

I want to compute the maximum value from the array. I have done with registers only but now i'am having trouble manipulating variables in memory. At the start i want to make first number the max value. I did `movl array(, %edi, 4), &max` it gives error, invalid char '&'. What's the correct way to do it? 
I have similar problem with the `decl &n` instruction.

In the code i use %edi for index and %eax for current value.

```
.data
    array:
        .int 31, 9, 42, 18, 40
    n:
        .int 5
    max:
        .int 0

.text
.globl _start

_start:
    movl $0, %edi
    movl array(, %edi, 4), &max
start_loop:
    incl %edi
    decl &n
    cmpl $0, n
    je exit_loop
    movl array(, %edi, 4), %eax
    cmpl max, %eax
    jle start_loop
    movl %eax, &max
    jmp start_loop

exit_loop:
    movl $1, %eax
    movl &max, %ebx
    int $0x80
```

Comment: What do you want that magical `&` to do? You don't need it to access variables.

Comment: You don't use `&` to denote an address. `max` _IS_ the address of the label. Your second problem is that on Intel x86 instructions can't take two memory operands. You'd have to break it up into two instructions using an intermediate register.

Comment: And the line I mean you'd have to break up is `movl array(, %edi, 4), &max`. An example would be `movl array(, %edi, 4), %eax` `movl %eax, max`

Comment: `cmpl $0, n` isn't necessary after `decl n` since the zero flag will be set  automatically by`decl` if `n` becomes zero, so no need for the extra comparison to zero.

Comment: Everything works fine now. Just one thing, now that i think of it, its not possible to have two memory operands because eveything has to go through the CPU, is that it?

Comment: Well, generally yes. But there are exceptions. Like `MOVS(B/W/D)` which move data from memory to memory with fixed index registers/pointers (ESI/EDI) without using any registers.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to compute the maximum value from the array.

A naive approach to solve the problem of getting the maximum value of an array is the following code (copy the data prologue):

```
_start:
    movl n, %ecx                ; %ecx is now equal to the array len
    lea array, %esi             ; %esi points to the beginning of the array
    xorl %edx, %edx             ; first maximum value is 0
start_loop:
    movl (%esi), %eax           ; get value from array to %eax
    cmpl %edx, %eax             ; is new value greater (or equal) to the current max?
    cmovge %eax, %edx           ; then replace it
    add $4, %esi                ; set pointer to next element of array
    loop start_loop             ; decrement %ecx and jump to label if not 0
exit_loop:
    movl $1, %eax               ; SYS_EXIT
    movl %edx, %ebx             ; copy max to 'exit status'
    int $0x80                   ; execute SYSCALL
```

Comment: movl array, %esi would move an integer to esi? It confuses me because array is label for an address.

Comment: I'm really not sure what you try to say to me. Nowhere in the above code a line like `movl array, %esi` even exists. I assigned `%esi` to the address of `array` with the instruction `lea array, %esi`. After that, I access the values of the array applying indirect addressing mode with `movl (%esi), %eax`. The instruction `movl array, %esi` would just move the first four bytes of `array` to `%esi` (`array` is a label and `movl` moves 4 bytes from that label to the destination).